# Scraping table with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape this table of occupation codes from IPUMS: https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/variables/OCC1950#codes_section.

I have (ugly) code that works (see below) but I was trying to use `rvest` and failing. I was wondering if there is a tidier way to do it?

Inspecting the page, I think the table has a selector `#dataTable > table > tbody` but I haven't seen `>` in a selector before and putting that selector in `html_node()` doesn't work:

```
"https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/variables/OCC1950#codes_section" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node('#dataTable > table > tbody') %>%
  html_table()

Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
```

Nor does using just `#dataTable` in the selector:

```
"https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/variables/OCC1950#codes_section" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node('#dataTable') %>%
  html_table()

Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE
```

The following does work, using `RCurl`, `jsonlite`, and `stringr` to slice through the page source. Perhaps the fact that the table seems to be in a json would explain why my `rvest` attempt fails, but I'm not sure.

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

txt <- "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/variables/OCC1950#codes_section" %>%
  getURL()

ipums <-
  txt %>%
  str_extract(".*Farmer.*") %>%
  str_extract("\\[.*false\\}\\]") %>%
  fromJSON()
```

Comment: I think this is one of the those web sites where rvest is not the best tool for the job.